# Strcmp using two pointers is causing a segmentaion fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I am trying to compare two pointers which I have basically made into strings. I have no idea how to fix this but when I run it it gives me a seg fault at the strcmp.

Here's my code:

```
int find_next_string(int *position, char str[], char * mem_start, int mem_size)
{
    int found = 0;
    char *temp2;
    int k = 0;
    int i=(*position+1);
    char *temp ;
    int temp3 = 0;

    temp = (char *) calloc(mem_size, sizeof(char));    
    temp2 = (char *) calloc(mem_size, sizeof(char));
    temp3=*position;
    while(i!=temp3 && found==0 && k==0){
        //for(j=0;i<mem_size;i++){
            temp2=mem_start;
            // j++;
            temp=strstr(temp2, str);
            if(strcmp(temp2, temp)==0){
                found=1;
                k=i;
            }
        //}
        if(i==mem_size)
        i=0;
        else
        i++;
    }
    if(found)
        print_line(k, mem_start, mem_size);
    //    1.  update the location to the first character matching str
    //    2.  print the 16-byte word containing the string and repeat
    //        printing words until all characters in str are displayed
    //    3.  set found to 1
    // if not found, do not change location and do not print
    free(temp);
    free(temp2);
    return found;
}
```

Comment: How do you call/use this function? And you do remember that strings (as used by `strcmp`) have a special terminator character, which means that the real length of a string is actually `stlen(str) + 1`.

Comment: * input:
 *     str is a string to find
 *     mem_start is starting address of the data
 *     mem_size is the number of bytes in the memory block
 * input/output:
 *     position is the location of the cursor.  If the string is found
 *     the position is updated to the memory offset for the first byte
 *     that matchs the string
 * return value:
 *     true if string found

Comment: once everything is input, I am supposed to find another spot in mem_start where it equals str

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, when adding important information please *edit your question* instead of adding it as comments.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is most likely not due to the `strcmp` calls, but due to the fact that you *reassign* `temp2` and then try to `free` the new pointer. You do the same with `temp`.

If those new pointers are not allocated with `malloc` (or `calloc` which is essentially `malloc` plus `memset`) then you will have *undefined behavior* which is a very common cause of crashes. And regarding `temp` it can point to the middle of some memory, and attempting to call `free` on that pointer (even if it point into the middle of a chunk allocated with `malloc`) is also UB.

The `free` function *must* be passed a pointer returned by `malloc`, or `NULL`, nothing else.

Comment: Well I know its during the strcmp because that's where it crashes when I gdb it. And I free the memory after I'm done using it.

Comment: @WilliamBrendanDagley Then you need to figure out what you're *really* passing to that `strcmp` call. When the crash happens and you catch it in GDB, have you tried to actually look at the pointers and the contents they point to?

Comment: @WilliamBrendanDagley Also, no you do not `free` the pointers you get from `calloc`. When you do e.g. `temp = strstr(...)` you *loose* the original pointer. Either *copy the strings*, or don't allocate dynamic memory at all for those pointers.

Comment: (gdb) p temp
$1 = 0x604820 "Blue Ridge yawns its greatness, where the Tigers play, here the sons of dear old Clemson reign supreme alway.Je8SgUsYACuRzwOQ8vJP5YMKBnAY95Z1aQQjiuxUWQzSjONbisoWhere the Blue Ridge yawns its greatness"...

Comment: (gdb) p temp2
$2 = 0x604270 "CLEMSON TIGERS!\n\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}\177\200\201\202\203\204\205\206\207\210\211\212\213\214\215\216\217\220\221\222\223\224\225\226\227\230\231\232\233\234\235\236\237\240\241\242\243\244\245\246\247\250\251\252\253\254\255\256\257\260\261\262\263\264\265\266\267\270\271"...

Comment: that's what temp and temp2 are

Comment: @WilliamBrendanDagley So, no string terminator in the correct places, leading `strcmp` to go out of bounds and also have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: so if I put 
temp2[mem_size-1]='\0';
would that fix temp2? And then Id just do the same for temp?

Comment: @WilliamBrendanDagley It *might* fix just that error, but it depends on that `mem_size` is valid, and that the terminator should be at that position. Also, like I said you have other problems too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic error:

```
temp=strstr(temp2, str);
if(strcmp(temp2, temp)==0){
```

If `strstr` does not find the string, then `temp` will be NULL. Passing `NULL` to `strcmp` causes undefined behaviour, and this could be the cause of the crash.

You need to check `if ( temp == NULL )` and take some action, before calling `strcmp`.